# Is there an option to get the stack trace of an android app?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to get the full stack trace of my application that runs on an emulator.
I managed to get the pid of the app with

```
adb shell ps
```

but jstack does not work.

Used

```
adb shell ps
```

to find the pid and then tried

```
jstack -l <pid>
```

got " no such process" message.

Answer (score 0):

Android apps are not run on the same kind of JVM that you would normally run Java apps in cross platform fashion, and JStack requires JVM.

Moreover, you query for process PID on the device, but you try to connect using jstack on your localmachine using that PID which cannto work. (You could use PIDs from my computer as well;))

Using ADB is a way to go IMO.

Comment: Do you know which adb command to use?

Comment: Use logcat 
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat